# Mysterious crash with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Can someone please explain why the following crashes in main() when the inner scope is exited?  I'm using Visual Studio 2013.  Though everything is fine with GCC 4.8.1, I suspect something is wrong in the code anyway.  I just don't get it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Person;  class PersonProxy;

class PersonInterface {
    public:
        virtual ~PersonInterface() = default;
        virtual PersonProxy* getProxy() const = 0;
        virtual void createProxy (Person*) = 0;
    };

class Person : public PersonInterface {
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::shared_ptr<PersonProxy> proxy;
    public:
        Person() = default;
        explicit Person (const std::string& n) : name(n) {}
    public:
        virtual PersonProxy* getProxy() const override {return proxy.get();}
        inline void createProxy (Person* p);
};

class PersonProxy : public PersonInterface {
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<Person> actual;
    public:
        explicit PersonProxy (Person* p) : actual (std::shared_ptr<Person>(p)) {}
        explicit PersonProxy (std::shared_ptr<Person> p) : actual (p) {}
        void rebind (std::shared_ptr<Person> p) {actual = p;}
        virtual PersonProxy* getProxy() const override {return actual->getProxy();}
        virtual void createProxy (Person* p) override {actual->createProxy(p);}
};

class Girl : public Person {
    public:
        Girl (const std::string& name) : Person (name) {createProxy (this);}
};

inline void Person::createProxy (Person* p) {
    proxy = std::shared_ptr<PersonProxy>(new PersonProxy(p));
}

int main() {
    {
        Girl* a = new Girl("a");
//      std::shared_ptr<Girl> a = std::make_shared<Girl>("a");  // Using this crashes with Visual Studio 2013 on the line 'a->getProxy()->rebind(b);'
        std::shared_ptr<Girl> b = std::make_shared<Girl>("b");
        a->getProxy()->rebind(b);
        std::cout << "rebind succeeded." << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Exited scope." << std::endl;  // Exiting scope crashes with VS 2013.
}
```

The error message I get with VS2013 is:

assertion failure

_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Comment: The code is fairly small, why not step through it with a debugger?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious would it really help?

Comment: @n.m. Probably not but I'm a masochist until I've had my morning bowl of Fruity Pebbles.

Comment: Is declaring two variables with same name in the same scope legal?

Comment: @Ginger.  I fixed the confusion now, though it is not relevant to the problem.  It is actual legal.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: *generally* no, and not in the OP's case.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus I was getting a slightly different error, but a crash nonetheless. Though the person who wrote the code had them in different scopes, there were in fact two smart pointers with the same name and type attached to the same resource. When I moved the second one out of the inner scope, that's when I found the issue, as it became a compile-time error. So, thanks for asking the question about scope!

Answer (score 15):

You've got two `shared_ptr`s trying to own the same pointer (and they don't know about each other). This results in both of them trying to free the same address.

`a` is trying to take total ownership of `this`. But then you pass `this` to `CreateProxy()` which creates a *new* `shared_ptr` that tries to take total ownership of `this`. The new `shared_ptr` doesn't know about `a`, so neither one shares their reference count. `shared_ptr`s need to share their reference count, not just the pointer itself.

If you want to share a pointer between two `shared_ptr`s, they need to both know about each other (so they can update their reference count). When `Girl` calls `createProxy()`, it needs to pass a `shared_ptr` to `this`.

Perhaps this would be a good time to use [`std::enable_shared_from_this()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Comment: So Girl must derive from std::enable_shared_from_this<Girl> and in its constructor call 'createProxy(shared_from_this());'  ?  Which means Person must have a createProxy (std::shared_ptr<Girl>) overload?

Comment: @prestokeys: why are you using all this proxy stuff.

Comment: @Cheers.  It's a long explanation.  I've confirmed with some professional programmers that it is needed for my program.  But I still haven't fixed the above problem using std::enable_shared_from_this<Girl> yet (still scratching my head).

Comment: @prestokeys: you could, but to be honest this design is getting hard to follow, so either redesigning it or using factories might simplify the logic and object lifetimes (from the consumer's perspective). Or you could use weak pointers instead of shared pointers.

Answer (score 9):

You're creating multiple reference count instances for the same pointer.
Creating a new shred_ptr from a pointer starts a new reference counter. When a reference counter reaches 0, the shared_ptr's default deleter calls delete on that pointer.

Because you have more than one reference counter for that pointer, the delete is called more than once.